# Как сделать короче код

Tags: python, синтаксис

Есть код.
как сделать короче последнюю строчку в коде

```
# вырез из списка только наименования товара  
res = [] # создание нового списка
lst = srez 
for el in lst:
    res.append(el.split(",")[0].replace('"','') +" "+ el.split(",")[1].replace('"','') +" "+ el.split(",")[2].replace('"','')+" "+ el.split(",")[3].replace('"','')+" "+ el.split(",")[4].replace('"','')+" "+ el.split(",")[5].replace('"','') )
```

Comment: Предполагая, что у вас в строках исходно данные json, полностью выкидываете строку и заменяете на `res.append(json.loads(el))`.

Comment: эта строчка выдает ошибку

Answer (score 2):

```py
" ".join(  # Объединяем через пробел
    map(  # Применяем маппинг к элементам этерируемого объекта
        lambda x: x.replace('"',''),  # Убираем в каждом элементе двойные кавычки
        el.split(",")[:6]  # Разбиваем строку по запятым, берём первые 6 элементов
    )
)
```

В одну строку:

```py
" ".join(map(lambda x: x.replace('"',''), el.split(",")[:6]))
```

---

А вообще, все Ваши 4 строки можно заменить на одну:

```py
res = list(" ".join(map(lambda x: x.replace('"',''), el.split(",")[:6])) for el in srez)
```

Comment: Поставил первый пример кода вместо последней строчки в моем коде. Ваш код не сработал. Вывелся пустой список - []

Comment: @Webos Я не знаю, как Вы его "поставили".